# How do I get the copyright property of the entry application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

My problem is this: I am writing a dll in C#, but it is Com Visible, so it can be referenced by a .NET application or used as a COM component by a non-.NET application (Forms, VB6, etc. etc.).
I want to get at the properties of the calling executable - ie. the Product Name, the Copyright etc. (all the things you can see if you right-click on the .EXE, select properties and go to the Details tab).
I can get at quite a few of these by simply using the properties of System.Windows.Forms.Application - ProductName is there, as is Product Version. However there is no FileVersion or Copyright property. It seems odd that some of these are implemented and some are not. Surely there must be a way (however tortuous) of getting the Copyright property of the calling application. I've Googled all over the place and hunted on the PInvoke website, all to no avail. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! Turns out to be dead easy:

```
FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.GetFileName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath));
```

FileVersionInfo then has properties for everything in the file's Version Resource, including LegalCopyright for the copyright. Works for any sort of application.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can expose [`AssemblyCopyright`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycopyrightattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) this way:

```
public string AssemblyCopyright
{
    get
    {
        object[] attributes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyCopyrightAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length == 0)
        {
            return "";
        }
        return ((AssemblyCopyrightAttribute)attributes[0]).Copyright;
    }
}
```

Also for other attributes you can do the same.

You can add an `AboutBox` to the project using `Add New Item` and see how other attribures are extracted.

Comment: Thanks but I'm afraid you haven't understood the question.. I know how to do it for a .NET application. I want to be able to do it for ANY application that may be referencing my dll, e.g. a Winforms or even a VB6 application.